# svmtrain is accepting complex number while svmclassify is not accepting complex number

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, svm, complex-numbers

the svmtrain function in matalb is accepting complex numbers for training.

But the svmclassify function is not accepting complex numbers. it is saying,

> Subscript indices must either be real positive
>       integers or logicals.

The support vectors are minimum ( 7 out of 106 values ) when I use the svmtrain function with the whole complex number.

The support vectors are many ( 72 out of 106 values ) when I use the svmtrain function by splitting the complex number into two parts. real(a) and imag(a)

If I use the whole complex number, the classification rate would be higher.

but the svmclassify function is not working on complex number ?